# only one xpath query to update values of various differents elements

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm trying to update with a single XPath expression several different elements that are at different levels (parent, child),suppose the following XML:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <row>
    <ELEMENT1>W</ELEMENT1>
    <ELEMENT2>IN</ELEMENT2>
    <ELEMENT3>RP</ELEMENT3>
    <ELEMENT4>KKK</ELEMENT4>
  </row>
  <row>
    0xFF0000
  </row>
  <row>
    <ELEMENT1>3</ELEMENT1>
    <ELEMENT2>I</ELEMENT2>
    <ELEMENT3>RP</ELEMENT3>
    <ELEMENT4>KKK</ELEMENT4>
  </row>
  <row>
    <ELEMENT1>1</ELEMENT1>
    <ELEMENT2>CC</ELEMENT2>
    <ELEMENT3>XX</ELEMENT3>
    <ELEMENT4>UUU</ELEMENT4>
  </row>
  <row>
    0xFFFF00
  </row>
</root>
```

for example if I want to edit values:

`XX value in ELEMENT3 of fourth row`

and

```
 0xFFFF00 value of fifth row
```

I can do it separately in two different XPath queries but I would do it in only one XPath query, I'm trying but when I get in one another no.
I would like to your proposal on possible combinations that might work.
thanks,

Comment: There is the union operator `|` so doing `/root/row[4]/ELEMENT3 | /root/row[5]` sounds simple.

Answer (score 0):

yes, I've already tried that option, I'll explain another example:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <customService>
    http://server:81/Portal/servlet
  </customService>
  <scales>        
    <core>
     <scale>500</scale>
     <scale>1000</scale>
     <scale>1500</scale>
     <scale>2000</scale>
     <scale>2500</scale>
    </core>
  </scales>       
</root>
```

if I do the query:

```
/root/scales/core/scale[5] | /root/customerService
```

and I edit values:

```
scale [5] to "9000"
```

and

```
customer service to "http://server:81/NewPort/servlet12"
```

then customerService update correctly, but all the elements scales (scale [1], scale [2], ... scale [5]) are all updated to "9000"